# Query Limit getting ignored

Tags: php, pdo, sql-limit

I have this code and its calculating all the rows in the column `correct` and igonring the `LIMIT 5`

The line of code thats getting ignored

---

```
$last5rate = $db->prepare("select sum(correct) 
from exams where username = :username ORDER BY testID DESC LIMIT 5");
```

---

here is the whole code

---

```
<?php

require('includes/config.php'); 

//if not logged in redirect to login page
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); } 
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$last5rate = $db->prepare("select sum(correct) from exams where username = :username ORDER BY testID DESC LIMIT 5");
$last5rate->execute(array(':username' => $username));
for($i=0; $rows = $last5rate->fetch(); $i++){
    //Edit this row
$last5  = $rows['sum(correct)'];
$last5final = $last5 / 10;
 }
echo $last5final;

?>
```

---

I have tried the following methods

---

```
select sum(correct) from exams where username 
= :username ORDER BY testID DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

AND

```
select sum(correct) from exams where username 
    = :username ORDER BY testID DESC LIMIT 5
```

---

Comment: I don't think LIMIT can work in this way, you'd have to use it in a join, I believe it will apply the limit after doing the sum

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`LIMIT` limits the amount of results it returns

Your `SUM` always returns 1 result, so your limit will not do anything.

You might need something like this (untested, just for example)

```
SELECT sum(correct) FROM(
    select correct from exams where username 
    = :username DESC LIMIT 5
)
```

I removed the order, fiddle with it as needed.

Comment: Whats the best method around this?

Comment: select whatever you want to limit in a subquery, then sum the 'correct' from that subquery. See example. Note that this is to show you the gist of what might look like, ymmv because of the order etc.